# Auto populating rows from another sheet conditional to a specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel, auto-populate, auto-populating

Hello i am trying to autopopulate rows from another sheet if a specific value if found in a specific cell. So far, i managed to do it manually by adding this line in Sheet #2 for each cell.

`=IF(OR('Le 2250'!$C48="Nouveau locataire",'Le 2250'!$C48="Décès", 'Le 2250'!$C48="Retention"), 'Le 2250'!$B48,"")`

I am trying to create a vba script that will generate each column in Sheet#2, and that will dynamically update regarding if i add a row in Sheet 1 or delete it.

Sheet1 is:

[image]

Sheet2 is:

[image]

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is the INDIRECT function

As an example:

```
=CELL("contents",INDIRECT("Sheet1!B5"))
```

This always pick up the value in Sheet1 Cell B5, regardless of changes in Sheet1.

For more information: [Excel INDIRECT Function](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html)

---

Edit: To directly answer the question with INDIRECT.

```
=IF(OR(INDIRECT("'Le 2250'!C48")="Nouveau locataire",INDIRECT("'Le 2250'!C48")="Décès"),CELL("contents",INDIRECT("'Le 2250'!B48")),"")
```

Comment: Can I integrate the if function in the cell function? I am not quiet understanding this cell(contents, function)

Comment: works like a charm. is there a way to integrate this function in vba so it populates all the rows?

Comment: Cell is a function that can return information on the cell.  The way it is used in this case was to return the contents of the cell.  For more information: [Excel Cell Function](https://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Cell-Function.html)